# How to have a different HTML id attribute for a check_box in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, forms, form-helpers

Using the form helper for check boxes, I need to change the `id` attribute. Normally I have something like this:

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, 'Please remember me' %>
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
```

Problem is, I'm already using another HTML element on the page with `id="remember_me"` and this conflicts with that. So I tried changing this `check_box` to:

```
  <%= f.label :remember_me_top, 'me' %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me_top, 'remember_me' %>
```

That gives me an error... How do I have the `name` of the check box as remember_me, but the `id` of it as remember_me_top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change checkbox id like this:

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, 'Please remember me', :for => "my_unquie_id" %>
<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :id => "my_unquie_id" %>
```

Also, if you want to change `name` attribute, add option to check_box: `:name => "my_unique_name"`